# ActiveX Control does not work on ASPX pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex

I have Created a C# ActiveX Control, and registered it successfully, I have Tried it on HTML Page and it works perfectly, but when I put it inside ASPX Page and use it, the Following error happened:

"JavaScript runtime error: Member not found."

the above error happen when I try to call any function of my ActiveX control

here is the code that working on HTML page, The exact same code dose not work on aspx page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test for c# dll</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function innit()
        {
            var obj = document.getElementById("barcodeReader");
            document.getElementById("txtInit").value = obj.myInit();
        }
        function takeImage()
        {
            var obj = document.getElementById("barcodeReader");
            document.getElementById("txtImg1").value = obj.takeImage();
            var t = "none";
            while(t == "none")
            {
                t = obj.getImage();
            }
            document.getElementById("txtImg").value = obj.getImage();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<OBJECT ID="barcodeReader" CLASSID="CLSID:2174C6FB-475C-4507-848C-26AAD312BD01"></OBJECT>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtInit">
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtImg1">
<br>
<textarea rows="10" cols="150" id="txtImg"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="btnClick" onclick="innit()">click</button>
<br>
<button id="btnimage" onclick="takeImage()">take-Image</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was on Security Setting, as I am running the web site from local host, I have to change the security setting of Local Intranet